# Creating a Vehicle Program

Tags: java, class, methods

Right now I'm doing some tasks from a java e-book that I've acquired, and unfortunately, I'm stuck. The main thought of this program is to create a Vehicle class, which along with a test program can increase, decrease and break the current speed.

The starting speed should be 0. I want the user to specify what speed the car should drive to (for an example 90 km/h). After hitting the speed(90 in this case)  I want the program to ask the user if he wants to decrease the speed to a given value, stay at the same speed, or break to 0. Should all of this be done in the testprogram, or should it be implemented into the Vehicle class?

I'm supposed to create a program from the following UML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/01fgM.png

This is my code so far:

```
public class Vehicle {
    int speed;

    //Constructor
    public Vehicle () {
        this.speed = 0;
    }

    public void increaseSpeed (int differenceInc) {
        this.speed += differenceInc;
    }

    public void decreaseSpeed (int differenceDec) {
        this.speed -= differenceDec;
    }

    public void brake() {

    }

    public int getSpeed () {
        return this.speed;
    }   
}
```

And this is my empty test class.

```
public class VehicleTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vehicle golf = new Vehicle();

    //Speed which should be accelerated to:
    Vehicle myHybrid = new Vehicle();

    System.out.println("You've hit the given speed. Do you want to stay at this speed, break, or decrease to another given speed?");

}

}
```

Comment: Well, it's not really that I don't understand arguments and methods, I'm not a native English speaker so sometimes it's hard to explain exactly what I mean. I've edited my post so you can understand what exactly I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the idea is to take an `int` for `increaseSpeed()`, so that you can increase the speed by that given integer. Also add the logic for hitting the speed limit in your `increaseSpeed` method.

So...

```
public void increaseSpeed (int amount) {
    if (speed + amount < MAX_SPEED) {  // Where MAX_SPEED is a static final int of value 90
        this.speed += amount;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Max speed reached. Want to exceed (y/n)?");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char c = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        if (c == 'y') {
            this.speed += amount;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do the same for `decreaseSpeed()`, of course. Don't forget to check if decreasing the speed doesn't result in a negative speed (unless, you consider a negative value of speed to be driving in reverse.

By the way, here I have hard-coded `MAX_SPEED` for simplicity. This is, of course, dependent on the road you are driving, so it is probably better to do this differently (e.g., a `Road` class that includes the particular attributes of a given road, or by passing both an integer for the amount you want to speedup with and an integer for the maximum speed).

Answer (score 0):

Well , first of all, welcome to Stack Overflow.

If you want a method to accept arguments (parameters) then you must declare said arguments and the arguments' types in the mehtod declaration:

```
    public void increaseSpeed (int augmentValue) {
        this.speed += augmentValue;
    }
```

You're also asking about software design: "should the component (Vehicle) user or client be able to set the augment value of the increaseSpeed mehtod?" . The answer relies on the design of said component. If your method will accept an argument then perhaps the method should also validate the input value and establish pre and post conditions.

Hope this helps.